# Display image on only one ngFor element

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngfor

I have a timeline component in my app generated with an ngFor loop. However i want to display an image in the first card element but with the ngFor the image is displayed several times.

html file

```
<timeline color='primary'>
    <timeline-item *ngFor="let note of notes;index as i">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-card [ngClass]="note.card ? 'card-item' : 'no-card' ">
        <ion-card-header>
          <b>Date:</b> {{note?.Created}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content [ngClass]="isMenuOpen[i] ? 'active' : 'inactive'" *ngFor='let ind of individuals'>
          <ion-list>
            <b>Injury On Arrival:</b> {{note?.Notes}}
          </ion-list>
          <ion-list>
            <b>Injury Desc:</b> {{ind.InjuryDesc}}
          </ion-list>
          <ion-list>
            Posted By: {{ind.FirstNameUser}} {{ind.LastNameUser}}
          </ion-list>
          <ion-list *ngFor='let img of pImages'>
                   <ion-col *ngIf='ind.Created === img.Added'>
                      <img src = "http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/{{img.Image}}"/>
                  </ion-col> 
          </ion-list>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </timeline-item>
  </timeline>
```

Comment: can you create one demo here: https://stackblitz.com/  if you want to display the first image only you may can try like {{img[0].Image}}

Comment: `<img src="image.png"  *ngIf="i == 0">`  check if index is 0. other wise it will not show.

Comment: @Najamussaqib What if the ``Card`` he wants to show does not fit with the index zero

Comment: i just gave him the Idea. Its his logic how he handles it.